# SQL ADD 1HOUR INTERVAL TO A QUERY

Tags: sql, date, group-by, intervals, mysql-8.0

I created a query that UNIONS two tables and makes a count of unanswered calls before an answered call.

Here is the query with the creation of the tables and some data added to it.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS answered;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS unanswered;


CREATE TABLE answered (
    ttime varchar(255),
    calledNumber varchar(255),
    callingNumber varchar(255),
    attendantNumber varchar(255),
    identifier varchar(255),
    company varchar(255),
    key12 varchar(255)
   
);

CREATE TABLE unanswered (
    ttime varchar(255),
    calledNumber varchar(255),
    callingNumber varchar(255),
    attendantNumber varchar(255),
    identifier varchar(255),
    company varchar(255),
    key12 varchar(255)
   
);

INSERT INTO answered (ttime, calledNumber, attendantNumber, callingNumber, identifier, company, key12) VALUES
('2022-12-19 04:13:00', '+123456',  '+2345672',  '+3234343', 'abcdefg212', '23343', 'Answered'),
('2022-12-19 04:37:00', '+123232',  '+2345671',  '+3234343', 'abcdefg213', '23343', 'Answered'),
('2022-12-19 06:47:00', '+127853',  '+2345671',  '+3231237', 'abcdefg214', '23344', 'Answered'),
('2022-12-19 18:30:00', '+566312',  '+1212212',  '+3231223', 'abcdefg222', '23345', 'Answered');


INSERT INTO unanswered (ttime, calledNumber, attendantNumber, callingNumber, identifier, company, key12) VALUES
('2022-12-19 04:23:00', '+123456',  '+2345672',  '+3234343', 'abcdefg215', '23343', 'Unanswered'),
('2022-12-19 04:24:00', '+123232',  '+2345671',  '+3234343', 'abcdefg216', '23343', 'Unanswered'),
('2022-12-19 06:27:00', '+127853',  '+2345671',  '+3231237', 'abcdefg217', '23344', 'Unanswered'),
('2022-12-19 17:47:00', '+127854',  '+2345676',  '+3231223', 'abcdefg218', '23345', 'Unanswered'),
('2022-12-19 17:07:00', '+127854',  '+1234216',  '+3231223', 'abcdefg219', '23345', 'Unanswered'),
('2022-12-19 12:47:00', '+125732',  '+9845646',  '+3231223', 'abcdefg220', '23345', 'Unanswered'),
('2022-12-19 13:47:00', '+127583',  '+1231221',  '+3231223', 'abcdefg221', '23345', 'Unanswered');



    WITH
        t1 AS (
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                ttime,
                calledNumber, 
                attendantNumber,
                callingNumber,
                identifier,
                company,
                key12
            FROM answered 
            
        ),
        t2 AS (
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                ttime,
                calledNumber, 
                '' as attendantNumber,
                callingNumber,
                identifier,
                company,
                key12
            FROM unanswered 

        ),
    t3 AS (
            SELECT ttime, calledNumber, attendantNumber, callingNumber, identifier, company, key12
            FROM t1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ttime, calledNumber, attendantNumber, callingNumber, identifier, company, key12
            FROM t2
          ),
    t4 AS (
            SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY callingNumber, company ORDER BY ttime) as row_numb,
                ttime, calledNumber, attendantNumber, callingNumber, identifier, company, key12
            FROM t3
          ),
    t5 AS (
            SELECT row_numb, ttime, calledNumber, attendantNumber, callingNumber, identifier, company, key12,
                lag(row_numb, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY callingNumber, company ORDER BY ttime) as info1
            FROM t4
            WHERE key12 = 'Answered'
          ),
    t6 AS (
            SELECT ttime, calledNumber, attendantNumber, callingNumber, identifier, company, key12,
            CASE 
                WHEN (row_numb-info1) = 1 THEN '1 attempt until answered'
                WHEN (row_numb-info1) = 2 THEN '2 attempt until answered'
                ELSE '3 attempt or more until answered'
            END AS key122
            FROM t5
          )
    SELECT * FROM t6
    ORDER BY ttime
```

Right now the ouput is the following:

```
ttime, calledNumber, attendantNumber, callingNumber, identifier, company, key12, key122

'2022-12-19 04:13:00', '+123456', '+2345672', '+3234343', 'abcdefg212', '23343', 'Answered', '1 attempt until answered'

'2022-12-19 04:37:00', '+123232', '+2345671', '+3234343', 'abcdefg213', '23343', 'Answered', '3 attempt or more until answered'

'2022-12-19 06:47:00', '+127853', '+2345671', '+3231237', 'abcdefg214', '23344', 'Answered', '2 attempt until answered'

'2022-12-19 18:30:00', '+566312', '+1212212', '+3231223', 'abcdefg222', '23345', 'Answered', '3 attempt or more until answered'
```

**I want to count only the unanswered calls that are only at a maximum of 1hour before of an unswared call and where the company and callingNumber are equal in both calls.**

So, with the given data, my desired output is the following:

```
ttime, calledNumber, attendantNumber, callingNumber, identifier, company, key12, key122

'2022-12-19 04:13:00', '+123456', '+2345672', '+3234343', 'abcdefg212', '23343', 'Answered', '1 attempt until answered'

'2022-12-19 04:37:00', '+123232', '+2345671', '+3234343', 'abcdefg213', '23343', 'Answered', '3 attempt or more until answered'

'2022-12-19 06:47:00', '+127853', '+2345671', '+3231237', 'abcdefg214', '23344', 'Answered', '1 attempt until answered'

'2022-12-19 18:30:00', '+566312', '+1212212', '+3231223', 'abcdefg222', '23345', 'Answered', '2 attempt or more until answered'
```

In the initial table Unanswered this rows should not be counted, because they are more than 1 hour away of an answered call.

```
('2022-12-19 17:07:00', '+127854',  '+1234216',  '+3231223', 'abcdefg219', '23345', 'Unanswered'),
('2022-12-19 12:47:00', '+125732',  '+9845646',  '+3231223', 'abcdefg220', '23345', 'Unanswered'),
('2022-12-19 13:47:00', '+127583',  '+1231221',  '+3231223', 'abcdefg221', '23345', 'Unanswered'),
('2022-12-19 05:27:00', '+127853',  '+2345671',  '+3231237', 'abcdefg217', '23344', 'Unanswered'),
```

I've tried some things but I did not reach any positive output.

**To sum all up, I need to change the query to be able to only count the calls that are at a maximum of 1hour before an answered call and that all the calls (answered and unanswered) have the same callingNumber and company columns.**

Comment: `WHERE EXISTS`...

Comment: @SamCohen-Devries I am not able to use that statement to the 1hour difference, I get the wrong output when trying to use that to get the answered vs unanswered. Is there a way tho show me how?

Comment: @SamCohen-Devries see what you think about my answer